# Elliot Haughin API verify credentials error

Tags: api, codeigniter, twitter

I am currently building an Twitter client application for campus project using Codeigniter and Elliot Haughin Twitter library. It's just a standard application like tweetdeck. After login, user will be directed to the profile page containing timline. I am using Jquery to refresh the timeline every 20 second. At the beginning, everything run smoothly until i found the following error at the random time : 
![the error][1]

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$request
>
> Filename: libraries/tweet.php
>
> Line Number: 205

I already search the web about this error but can't find satisfied explanation. So I tried to find it myself and found that the error comes out because credentials validation error. I tried to var_dump the line **$user = $this->tweet->call('get', 'account/verify_credentials');** and resulting an **empty array**. My question is how come this error showed up when user already login and even after updated some tweets? is there any logical error in my script or is it something wrong with the library? Could anyone explain whats happening to me? please help me...
Here's my codes:

**The Constructor** Login.php

```
<?php 

    class Login extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->load->library('tweet');
            $this->load->model('login_model');

        }

        function index()
        {
            $this->tweet->enable_debug(TRUE); //activate debug


            if(! $this->tweet->logged_in())
            {
                $this->tweet->set_callback(site_url('login/auth'));
                $this->tweet->login();
            }
            else
            {

                redirect('profile');
            }

        }

        //authentication function
        function auth()
        {
            $tokens = $this->tweet->get_tokens();
            $user = $this->tweet->call('get', 'account/verify_credentials');

            $data = array(
                'user_id' => $user->id_str,
                'username' => $user->screen_name,
                'oauth_token' => $tokens['oauth_token'],
                'oauth_token_secret' => $tokens['oauth_token_secret'],
                'level' => 2,
                'join_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
            );


            //jika user sudah autentikasi, bikinkan session
            if($this->login_model->auth($data) == TRUE)
            {
                $session_data = array(
                    'user_id' => $data['user_id'],
                    'username' => $data['username'],
                    'is_logged_in' => TRUE 
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
                redirect('profile');
            }

        }

    }
```

**profile.php (Constructor)**

```
<?php

class Profile extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('tweet');
        $this->load->model('user_model');

    }

    function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == TRUE)
        {
            //jika user telah login tampilkan halaman profile

            //load data dari table user
            $data['biography'] = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('user_id'));

            //load data user dari twitter
            $data['user'] = $this->tweet->call('get', 'users/show', array('id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')));

            $data['main_content'] = 'private_profile_view';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            //jika belum redirect ke halaman welcome
            redirect('welcome');
        }
    }

    function get_home_timeline()
    {
        $timeline = $this->tweet->call('get', 'statuses/home_timeline');
        echo json_encode($timeline);

    }

    function get_user_timeline()
    {
        $timeline = $this->tweet->call('get', 'statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => $this->session->userdata('username')));
        echo json_encode($timeline);
    }

    function get_mentions_timeline()
    {
        $timeline = $this->tweet->call('get', 'statuses/mentions');
        echo json_encode($timeline);
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('welcome');
    }
}

/** end of profile **/
```

**Default.js (The javascript for updating timeline)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                //bikin tampilan timeline jadi tab
                $(function() {
                                $( "#timeline" ).tabs();
                            });


                //home diupdate setiap 20 detik
                update_timeline('profile/get_home_timeline', '#home_timeline ul');
                var updateInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    update_timeline('profile/get_home_timeline', '#home_timeline ul');
                },20*1000);   

                //user timeline diupdate pada saat new status di submit
                update_timeline('profile/get_user_timeline', '#user_timeline ul');

                //mention diupdate setiap 1 menit
                update_timeline('profile/get_mentions_timeline', '#mentions_timeline ul');
                var updateInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    update_timeline('profile/get_mentions_timeline', '#mentions_timeline ul');
                },60*1000);


});

function update_timeline(method_url, target)
{
        //get home timeline
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: method_url,
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(result) {
            $(target).empty();
            for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                $(target).append('<li><article><img src="'+ result[i]['user']['profile_image_url'] +'"><a href="">'+ result[i]['user']['screen_name'] + '</a>'+ linkify(result[i]['text']) +'</li></article>');
            }
          }
        });
}


function linkify(data)
{
    var param = data.replace(/(^|\s)@(\w+)/g, '$1@<a href="http://www.twitter.com/$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
    var param2 = param.replace(/(^|\s)#(\w+)/g, '$1#<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
    return param2;      
}
```

That's the codes. Please help me. After all, I really appreciate all comments and explanation from you guys. Thanks

NB: sorry if i had bad English grammar :-)

Comment: I've noticed the error occurred and get fixed automatically about every 30 minutes.. but, I am not sure. It's really random. I tried to login and make some tweet, it's just fine, but after 30 minutes the error occurred, again :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a call to `statuses/home_timeline` which is an unauthenticated call. The rate limit for unauthenticated calls is **150 requests per hour**.

> [Unauthenticated calls are permitted **150 requests per hour**.
>   Unauthenticated calls are measured against the public facing IP of the
>   server or device making the request.](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting)

This would explain why you see the problem at the peak of your testing.

With the way you have it setup you would expire your rate limit after **50 minutes** or less.

I suggest changing the interval to a higher number, **30 seconds** would do. That way you'll be making **120 requests per hour** and under the rate limit.

Comment: wow, Thank you so much. Now, i am limiting the request interval for 30 sec and don't see the error again.  base on your calculation, I would safe with 30 sec setting and still have 30 more requests access. But, frankly speaking I am still worrying about what if my user make more than 30 request in an hour? I would get the same error, right? I've read the documentation that POST request is not limited, but the workflow of my application should refresh the timeline right after the user making any post so he/she would see his/her update in real time. any suggestion for this? thanks :-)

Comment: Also, I found in the response header something like "X-RateLimit-Limit:20000" and "X-RateLimit-Remaining:19999". what that's really mean? I found in the documentation that Feature-based rate limit is applied in conjunction with API-REST limit and the request will fail if either limit is exhausted. Why some features need this special limit if there's the "superpower" REST-API limit still applied to them? It doesn't make sense right? Could you explain to me what this really is? Thank you :-)

Comment: Ok, I'll tell you if I can get a +1 :). Anyways, you integrated the CI library. I have a WebApp that makes a variable amount of calls so I needed to do like your describing, make the request on the JS side and forward the request to POST. As long as your making the actual API call from Javascript your server won't get limited, your user will :). I hear the 20k limit is applied to applications in testing & on the special whitelist.

Comment: hey, i tried to give you +1 , but i don't have enough reputation to do it now. So, sorry :-(

Comment: oh, yeah it looks like you need more rep. Its ok i was half joking. GL on the project.