# Twitter Login in Codeigniter with elliothaughin/ gives error

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-oauth

Trying to authenticate with Twitter in codeigniter. It goes to twitter and comes back but giving the error. Here is the error and the code. Any tip?

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$request
Filename: libraries/tweet.php
Line Number: 205

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$error
Filename: libraries/tweet.php
Line Number: 205

bool(false)

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: friendship
Filename: controllers/tweet_connect.php
Line Number: 63
```

Here is the code;

```
function index()
    {
        echo 'hi there';
    }

  function auth()
  {
    $tokens = $this->tweet->get_tokens();

    // $user = $this->tweet->call('get', 'account/verify_credentiaaaaaaaaals');
    // 
    // Will throw an error with a stacktrace.

    $user = $this->tweet->call('get', 'account/verify_credentials');
    var_dump($user);

    //$friendship   = $this->tweet->call('get', 'friendships/show', array('source_screen_name' => $user->screen_name, 'target_screen_name' => 'elliothaughin'));
    //var_dump($friendship);

    if ( $friendship->relationship->target->following === FALSE )
    {
    //$this->tweet->call('post', 'friendships/create', array('screen_name' => $user->screen_name, 'follow' => TRUE));
    }

    //$this->tweet->call('post', 'statuses/update', array('status' => 'Testing #CodeIgniter Twitter library by @elliothaughin - http://bit.ly/grHmua'));

    $options = array(
    'count' => 10,
    'page'  => 2,
    'include_entities' => 1
    );

    //$timeline = $this->tweet->call('get', 'statuses/home_timeline');

    //var_dump($timeline);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using an old library: https://github.com/elliothaughin/codeigniter-twitter/pull/25#commitcomment-1988684

You might have hit the request limit: [Elliot Haughin API verify credentials error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8857575/183254)

There have also been a lot of changes to the twitter api since that lib was released ~2 years ago--it's possible the lib doesn't work anymore in its current state.

Might want to look into the libraries twitter offers: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php